# what is MVP application pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvp

what is MVP design pattern in .net? how it is differ from MVC ? and is it require any template like the MVC 2 in asp.net ? If yes ,from where I can download it ? and how to create basic test MVP application ? I am using VS 2008 . Please guide me . I have knowledge of MVC but not know about MVP . 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MVP is the [Model View Presenter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter)**

It (nor MVC) is specific to .net or any framework.

Here is an article comparing MVC MVP and MVVM
http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/mvc-vs-mvp-vs-mvvm/

You may want to listen to this episode of [Hansleminutes Discussing MVVM](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast241TheMVVMPatternWithLaurentBugnion.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

MVP is a code design pattern. By using MVP pattern in our application, we can categorize code in three different layers **Model View** and **Presenter**.

- **View** is responsible for holding all UI aliments.
- **Model** provides a data.
- **Presenter** is a mediator and responsible for holding all business logics.